# How to connect to FTP server with TLS authentication in Rails Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftps

I have setup FTP server and enabled TLS/SSL to the server following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04). Once the setup was done, I tried to connect to it from FileZilla and it worked. Now I want to do the same with my rails application.

I came across similar questions and there were some solutions. But all the solutions suggested ignoring the verification as:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

But this beats the purpose of having FTP server with TLS enabled.
I came across an article that suggested setting `ssl: true` like:

```
ftps = Net::FTP.new(
    host,
    ssl: true,
    username: username,
    password: password
)
```

However, this did not work. I get

> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate)

I found some [references](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.5.0/class/OpenSSL=3a=3aSSL=3a=3aSSLContext.html#I_SET_PARAMS) about the parameters but am confused about how to use them.

Comment: TLS serves two very important purposes: Endpoint verification and traffic encryption. The traffic encryption still works without endpoint (certificate) verification, so it's still useful. In all honesty FTP is a creaky, antiquated protocol and TLS support has been bolted on top. If you want security use SSH and/or SCP.

Answer (score 2):

You have a server with a self signed certificate, SSL will fail to verify that **always**. Right now you have three ways to solve that:

1. Change your code so it accepts self signed certificates (you already stated this won't work for you).
2. Request a valid certificate (Letsencrypt seems like a good option).
3. Use [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) to create "valid" certificates for development.

If your FTP server is a public server, you should go with #2. #3 is a big help if you're just doing some experiments or setting a local development server.

Comment: Yes. Makes sense because the response I am getting was stating something about self signed certificate. I was suspicious about that but was not sure. However, I am confused why connecting from FileZilla worked.

Comment: Not familiar with FileZilla at all, but you should check if it has some option to skip certificate validation

Comment: If you need a cert, [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) is a fantastic and free option. Just be aware you need to periodically renew your cert or they'll start failing validation again due to having expired.

Comment: LetsEncrypt requires some valid domain. I don't have that. I am trying to get a certificate for ftp server. Am I missing something @tadman

Comment: @Aayush If this is development/hobby server you can set your own certificate with `mkcert`. If it's a corporate server you should thing about setting your own corporate CA or something

Comment: Getting a domain is trivial as there are many free domain registration services like [.tk](http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html?lang=en) and dynamic DNS services like [Dyn](https://dyn.com) which give you one at no cost.